# Get output console tail and save to string Java?

Tags: java, apache-tailer

I use the apache tailer for read end of line, if there is adding new line inside file log the program will print just end of line, it's like "tail -f" from linux, i have the output tail to send with String.

Can i get the output tail and save to string for my code below ?

```
public class LogTailTest {

/**
* TailerListener implementation.
*/
static public class ShowLinesListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void handle(String line) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    TailerListener listener  = new ShowLinesListener();
    File file = new File("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test.log");

    Tailer tailer = new Tailer(file, listener, 10000, true, true);
    tailer.run();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    tailer.stop();

}

}
```

When i run above program it's direct to output console

Answer (score 0):

You define what to do every time a new line is *tailed* by your program. This behaviour is defined in the method *handle* of class *ShowLinesListener*:

```
@Override
public void handle(String line) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

All you have to do is change this line

```
System.out.println(line);
```

to do what you want with it. As you are already using [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library (that's where the [TailerListener](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListener.html) and [TailerListenerAdapter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListenerAdapter.html) classes are defined), you can use [FileUtils.writeStringtoFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) method to write the contents of the line just tailed to another file.

Your class would look like this:

```
public class LogTailTest {

/**
* TailerListener implementation.
*/
static public class ShowLinesListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void handle(String line) {
        FileUtils.writeStringtoFile(new File("/path/to/file"),
                                    line,
                                    Charset.defaultCharset())
    }
}
```